# Integrating Google OAuth Authorization in my web-app

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, google-apps

I am building a web-app where I need to access list of spreadsheets from Google Docs (of Google Apps)

I want to authenticate using OAuth.

How can I do it in my PHP application?

One important thing, I want to authenticated on my user behalf. My application will run in background, and user will get email regarding list of spreadsheets associated with his/her account. I don't want a script that will need user to enter his/her email-id and password everytime script runs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367529/how-to-provide-oauth-services-from-website/6368524#6368524

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768132/google-data-api-two-legged-auth-token-reuse/4809739#4809739

Comment: FIRST google result for "Google Docs OAuth PHP" is http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/auth/oauth.html.  How did you miss this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is an overview of **OAuth usage with Google**:
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=61017

Next, here is a more **in-depth overview of OAuth usage with Google**: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/GettingStarted.html

Next, here is a sample of how to do **2 legged OAuth with PHP**:
http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2008/11/2-legged-oauth-in-php.html

Finally, here is the **Google Documents List API** (that you will most likely need to use):
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

Enjoy!  *(And remember to vote up if you liked this answer)*